# Add word wrap after comma in a bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table . I want to use word wrap property after the comma in the table but its not working.

I tried to increase table width still its not working ..

The code is:

```
<div class="smart-table-container" style="width:60%;float:left" id="bgcolor">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
    <tr class="app-table-header">
      <td st-sort="header1">header1</td>
      <td st-sort="header2">header2</td>
      <td st-sort="header3">header3</td>
    </tr>
<tr class="app-table-row st-selected " st-select-row="trigger" st-select-mode="single "> 
  <td>{{trigger.table}}</td>
  <td>{{trigger.table}}</td>
  <td style="word-break: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; ">{{trigger.table}}
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  <div>
```

So likewise i apply the "word-break : break-word" directly on on the 5th Column but i doesn't work.

Suggestions would be helpful.

[The 5th Column in the table needs the word wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyTR9.png)

Comment: Would be good if you provide some code. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is not possible to break the word based on some value inside the text. Generally it will break the words based on space inside the text. if you use `word-break:break-all` then only it will separate the word without having space also. In your text, if you have space after comma, and use `word-break:break-word` that will break the word only after comma. check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n73grhxL/10/

Comment: But the word-break : break word is not breaking word after comma. is it becos their is no space after comma?? Pls Refer the attached image as well